# Error executing shell command in pig script

Tags: apache-pig

I have a pig script where in the beginning I would like to generate a string of the dates of the past 7 days from a certain date (later used to retrieve log files for those days). 
I attempt to do this with this line:
    %declare CMD7 `input= ; for i in {1..6}; do  d=$(date -d "$DATE -i days" "+%Y-%m-%d"); input="\$input\$d,"; done; echo \$input`

I get an error :
    " ERROR 2999: Unexpected internal error. Error executing shell command: input= ; for i in {1..6}; do  d=$(date -d "2012-07-10 -i days" "+%Y-%m-%d"); input="$input$d,"; done;. Command exit with exit code of 127"
 however the shell command runs perfectly fine outside of pig. I am really not sure what is going wrong here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

I have got a working solution but not as streamlined as you want, essentially I don't manage to get Pig to execute a complex shell statement in the declare.

I first wrote a shell script (let's call it 6-days-back-from.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$1
for i in {1..6}; do d=$( date -d "$DATE -$i days" +%F ) ; echo -n "$d "; done
```

Then a pig script as follow (let's call it days.pig):

```
%declare my_date `./6-days-back-from.sh $DATE`
A = LOAD 'dual' USING PigStorage();
B = FOREACH A GENERATE '$my_date';
DUMP B
```

note that *dual* is a directory containing a text file with a single line of text, for the purpose of displaying our variable

I called the script as follow:

```
pig -x local -param DATE="2012-08-03" days.pig
```

and got the following output:

```
({(2012-08-02),(2012-08-01),(2012-07-31),(2012-07-30),(2012-07-29),(2012-07-28)})
```