# How to do I load files with parameterized names in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

I have just started using Pig to analyze a bunch of log files using Hadoop, and I need to load different files depending on the output of a previous calculation.
For example, if the output of the calculation is 0x18e0, I need to load a file called 0x18e0.txt.
How do I give parameterized file names in the LOAD statement?

In python, it's really straightforward to do this:

```
x = str(var)     
File = open( x + '.txt', 'r')
```

Is there a similarly simple way to do this in Pig?
I cannot give the input in command line like

> pig -param input=`x.txt`

because I don't know the value of x before I run the script.

I see another option of specifying an input file itself as the parameter as described here https://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution but this seems unduly roundabout. Is there another solution for this?

Comment: what kind of values can x take?

Comment: I've given an example above. x is just a string. In my case, x is a hexadecimal number that is represented as a string concatenated with a .txt, to make it a text file.

Comment: would `%declare` answer your need ?

Comment: %declare is a preprocessing step. So I need to declare the variable via %declare at the top of the script. Can I do some computation and assign the output of that computation to a variable via %declare? I thought I couldn't do that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by: (a) doing the pre-processing in the command line, or (b) using `declare` and calling a bash script:

Approach (a): In this example whatever goes between the backticks (`) is the preprocessing that results in the hexadecimal number that you want to use as the name of the file:

> pig -param input=`hdfs dfs -cat file_list.txt | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="";}{if
> (NR == 1) print; else print ","$0;}'`.txt script.pig

Approach (b). Create a bash script that does the processing you need to get x:

> #!/bin/bash
>
> #HERE YOU PUT CODE THAT PRINTS OUT THE HEX NUMBER

Then a pig script as follows:

> %declare x `./my_script.sh`
>
> ...

In approach (b), you don't really need to create a Bash script, since you could do the pre-processing using command line tools and backticks (as shown).

Similar approaches have been suggested in other StackOverflow answers. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277533/load-multiple-files-with-piglatin-hadoop/18278587#18278587) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586881/error-executing-shell-command-in-pig-script).